# Selectively save associated models in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I have the following associations

User hasOne Person

Person hasOne Contacts, Address, Student, and Employee

using saveAssociate I can create User and Person at the same time, however what I want is that I can also create Contacts, Address and either Student or Employee (determined by User.user_type) simultaneously.

can I do that with one call to saveAssociate? Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I do that with one call to saveAssociate?

Yes - you can.

(It's shown quite clearly in the CakePHP book in the section about "Saving your data".)

Comment: Well I know I can create the 4 associated models with one call of saveAssociated... but what if I just want to make 3 of the 4?

Comment: Then only pass 3 of the 4 in the array when you save.

Comment: I just realized about the whole data array a bit later. Thanks.